# Understanding comoving frame in an expanding universe?

Tags: coordinate-systems, astrophysics, velocity, space-expansion

A particle is moving in a universe that is expanding with a constant acceleration (i.e. expansion of universe is accelerating). I am considering 2 cases where the particle is (1) constantly accelerating and (2) moving with constant velocity. What would we observe the motion of the particle to be like in a comoving frame in both of the above cases?

Attempt: I think (1) if acceleration is same as acceleration of expansion of universe, it will be observed to have constant velocity (2) observed to decelerate. I am not sure and my understanding of comoving vs proper coordinates is fuzzy. If someone would clarify the concepts and provide possible solutions with explanation/equations if applicable that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

## Comoving Distance & Proper Distance

You can think of the expanding space as a grid expanding at a certain rate. To keep it simple, lets consider a two dimensional, square grid. Each side of a square is a constant $d$. If we wish to measure a distance between two points in space we might say, the distance between $A$ and $B$ is $3d$ if the sides of three squares separate between them. This distance remains the same as the grid stretches, since no new squares are added to it and the separation between $A$ and $B$ will remain $3d$. This is the **comoving distance** which remains constant.

But we also say that the grid is expanding, therefore there is a measure that grows larger as the stretching of the grid progresses, it is known as the **proper distance**.  In order to get the proper distance between the two points we have to multiply the comoving coordinate, $d$, by what is known as the *scale factor* $a(t)$ which does increase with time. If you are interested, the scale factor comes from the [FLRW metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) and can be calculated using [Hubble Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law). The proper distance is given by $$d_p(t) = a(t)d$$

## Expansion of the Universe & Hubble Law

The expansion of the universe, is usually likened to that of the surface of an inflating balloon. Every point is expanding away from every other point with a rate that is dependent on the separation distance. This is given by Hubble Law
$$\dot a(t) = H a(t)$$
You can multiply both sides of the formula by the comoving $d$ to get the proper quantities. In general, the Hubble constant $H$ is not a constant but depends on time with a changing manner throughout the history of the universe. But the Hubble constant today $H_0$ varies very slowly, that for a lot of intents and purposes it is effectively a constant

## Peculiar Velocities

An object can have a motion relative to its comoving frame. We usually refer to it as a **peculiar velocity** and it fits into the Hubble equation as such
$$\dot{r}(t) = Hr(t) + v_p(t)$$ where the quantities here are of proper distance. You can use it to answer questions about bodies with motion relative to their comoving frame as observed from a certain point, and so on.

These are all very simplified explanations, but I hope they manage clarify some points.